# Instalação do Angular CLI fica parada

Tags: npm, angular-cli

Quando uso o comando `install -g @ angular/cli` o NodeJS começa a carregar todas as dependências do Angular, mas quando começar a fazer o download do arquivo `chokidar@1.7.0` o ele fica parado e não carrega mais e também não gera erros. Tentei instalar o chokidar individualmente e vi que no endereço que ele tenta pegar o arquivo o mesmo não se encontra com conteúdo apenas com isto `{}`.

Para verificar o que digo é só tentar no NodeJS o comando `install -g @chokidar` e vai ver o que digo. Agora a questão é: como faço para instalar o Angular sendo que tem este problema?

Comment: Está no Windows? Tentou rodar o `cmd` com privilégios administrativos? Pode tentar limpar o cache do npm rodando `npm cache clean`

Comment: `@angular/cli` não depende do `chokidar`, veja [Dependency status for angular - @angular/cli](https://david-dm.org/angular/angular-cli?view=list), também podes ver no *GitHub* o arquivo [package.json](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/package.json#L43) na lista de dependências não consta o `chokidar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Então rodei sempre como administrador, eu cheguei a desinstalar e  instalar outra versão do node mais recente, só não tentei limpar o cache

Comment: Para conseguir instalar tive que instalar versão anterior, pq se não colocar versão você acaba pegando a ultima versão, que pelo que vejo esta sempre com problema, solução foi então:
npm install -g @angular/cli@1.6.2